# Connect to remote database from Heroku using a static IP via Proximo

Tags: heroku, proximo

I have a nodejs app (parse-server-example) that I want to connect to a remote mongoDB that has access controlled via IP whitelist.

I have configured Proximo, and my startup Procfile looks like this:

`web: bin/proximo npm start`

However, I get timeout errors on trying to contact the Proximo proxy.

The error looks like:

```
2016-03-08T21:18:18.190795+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/parse/classes/_User" host=something.herokuapp.com request_id=064586db-9b43-4b11-9b80-25b4b521e0bd fwd="129.51.22.25" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30001ms status=503 bytes=0
```

If I remove the proximo start call (and just have "npm start") and also open my database server to all IPs, then it all works fine. 
But I would prefer to have the security of the static and whitelisted IP.

I have the feeling I am missing something very simple configuration-wise, but I can't find what it is - any help appreciated :)

Comment: were you able to sort this out?

Comment: No, I never found a solution. I ended up ditching the whole thing and using a separate provider service (back4app.com).